# rspec Always Returns Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rspec

I run:

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec/
```

And receive this message:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core.rb:78:in `require': no such file to load -- rspec/expectations (LoadError) 
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.0 .1/lib/rspec/core.rb:78:in `<top (required)>' from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.0 .1/lib/rspec/autorun.rb:1:in `require'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/autorun.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/bin/rspec:2:in `require'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/bin/rspec:2:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin/rspec:19:in `load'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin/rspec:19:in `<main>'
```

In my Gemfile:

```
group :development do
gem 'rspec-core', '2.0.1'
gem 'annotate', :git => 'git://github.com/ctran/annotate_models.git'
end
```

What do I need to do in order to run rspec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rspec-rails`, which installs core, and others required by rspec.

http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-rails/frames

Comment: Running $ gem install rspec-rails fixed this. Thanks!